# Is there an easy way to pack a node_modules folder and a lambda handler using archive_file?

Tags: terraform

Got a lambda handler written in Typescript. So I have a compile script:

```
    "precompile": "rm -rf dist",
    "compile": "npx tsc --moduleResolution node --outDir dist --sourceMap false",
```

Works fine. Then I thought I'd zip up the `dist` folder and the `node_modules` before uploading (with a prune beforehand):

```
# zip the handler code before sending it
data "archive_file" "lambda_zip_file" {
  type = "zip"
  source_dir = "${path.module}/../dist"
  source_dir = "${path.module}/../node_modules"
  output_path = "${path.module}/../${var.tempfolder}/${local.prefix}.zip"
}
```

[archive_file docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/archive/latest/docs/data-sources/archive_file)

OK well `source_dir` doesn't allow two sources. Or an array of sources. So my alternative is to `cp` the `node_modules` folder to the `dist` folder before I call Terraform. Which isn't a big deal, just wondering if there's a better way that I'm not seeing. Cleaner if I don't have a temp folder to in my file tree.

Terraform 1.0.x

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to comment, but sadly cannot.
So I don't think there isn't really a better option rather than copying all the needed stuff into one directory and the archiving. You could point specific source files (https://stackoverflow.com/a/56928455/19635908), but I don't think that's what you want as you want the whole `node_modules` and `dist`.
What I could recommend though is trying out a function packager for node which can do all the building and zipping for you.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/funpack
Let me know what you think

Comment: Did not know about function packager, I like it